# Android thread handler not receiving message

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

i ahve a problem with a thread handler receiving a message. all other thread i implemnted this pattern works fine. here my code:

**Start thread**

```
InternalScoresThread t = new InternalScoresThread(
    this.game.getApplicationContext(),
    this.map.fileName, this.map.getCurrentTime(),
    new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            Log.d("DEBUG", "message received");

            if (msg.getData().getBoolean("record")) {

                Player.this.showtRecordMessage();

            } else {

                Player.this.showtFinishMessage();
            }

            Player.this.showTimeMessage();
            Player.this.showRestartMessage();
        }
});

t.start();
```

**Thread class**

```
public class InternalScoresThread extends Thread {

    private Handler handler;
    private String map;
    private float time;
    private Context context;

    public InternalScoresThread(Context context, String map, float time, Handler handler) {

        this.context = context;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.map = map;
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {         

        Log.d("DEBUG", "thread started");

        Database db = Database.getInstance(this.context);
        float bestTime = db.getBestTime(this.map);
        db.addRace(this.map, this.time);

        Log.d("DEBUG", "race added");

        Message msg = new Message();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putBoolean("record", this.time < bestTime || bestTime == 0);
        msg.setData(b);
        this.handler.sendMessage(msg);

        Log.d("DEBUG", "message sent");
    }
}
```

The "thread started, "race added" and "message sent" logs appear in logcat, but not the "message received" in the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but Google.

The problem is that you created the Handler in the UI thread.  It then receives messages on that thread.  You need to create the Handler in the new thread:

```
public void run() {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "creating Handler in thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    Looper.prepare();
    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "message received");
        }
    };
    Looper.loop();
```

Comment: And why is that a problem? He wants the handler in the UI thread because he has to update the UI.

Comment: Perhaps my answer could have been worded better.  The point is that he is sending and receiving the message on the same thread.  The handler is not listening on the new thread, but on the old thread that created it (which is later sending the message).  I'm pretty sure he is trying to send messages to the new thread.

Answer (score 6):

well, I dunno why, but dispatchMessage() instead of sendMessage() solved the problem...

Comment: Do you have any other explanation for why this might have been happening? I am seeing this issue about 50% of the time

Comment: dispatchMessage() directly calls handleMessage() in the same thread, so it doesn't really solve the problem of communicating between threads.

Comment: What @Memetic says is correct. If you plan to update any UI when a message is received, using `dispatchMessage(Message)` will throw an error immediately. You can try to use `sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(Message)`. In my case, I was calling two methods one after the other that both used messaging. Delaying the second method call by 3s using a Countdown Timer solved the problem.